# ansible to display the value as well eventhough the string does not match

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am trying to find whether the host VM's are set with ssh connection is 36000.
Below is my code..

```
  tasks:
    - name: To check SSH connection is set to 36000
      lineinfile:
       dest: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
       line: "ClientAliveInterval 36000"
      check_mode: yes
      register: presence
      failed_when: presence.changed
```

It actually works fine, but i would like to get the ClientAliveInterval value printed in the output. 
Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

> It actually works fine, but i would like to get the ClientAliveInterval value printed in the output.

What you're asking for isn't a single module in Ansible.  You'll first have to read in the file, then print out the line(s) that contain the value you want in your output:

```
    - name: 'Read in a line'
      slurp:
        src: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
      register: found_lines

    - name: 'Show the line read'
      debug:
        msg: "{{ found_lines['content'] | b64decode | regex_search('^ClientAliveInterval.*') }}"
```

When I run that on my test system, I get this for the final output:

```
TASK [Show the line read] ****************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "ClientAliveInterval 36000"
}
```

If you need to reference the value on the line, you'll have to replace the "debug: / msg:" block with a ["set_fact:"](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/set_fact_module.html) call instead.

The "b64decode" is needed because the ["slurp:"](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/slurp_module.html) module sanitizes the file contents as Base64 encoded text.